# Can we bundle Chrome installer with Packaged App?

Tags: google-chrome-app

We have built Packaged App for our Web Application.

Is it possible to provide Chrome installer in a Packaged App bundle or somehow trigger Chrome installation in the background from Packaged App.

Currently Chrome Browser is separate Dependancy for using Packaged Apps so it is difficult to convince Users to first install Chrome browser.

Also, people can install the App for any location as a complete package.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible yet, but you can star http://crbug.com/173762 to get notified when it does work.